# How to generate a user-friendly test overview from a GitHub Action, without using unverified Marketplace Actions?

Tags: unit-testing, continuous-integration, github-actions, xunit, trx

I have a GitHub Action that runs a C# xUnit test suite. From this test output I want to generate a user-friendly test report like the ones you can get on Jenkins or TeamCity.

There is an Action in the GitHub Actions Marketplace called [Publish Unit Test Results](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/publish-unit-test-results). It looks like it does what we want, but I don't trust it, and even if I personally trusted it, my workplace has a policy to only allow those GitHub Marketplace Actions that have the ["verified creator" badge](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/github-marketplace/github-marketplace-overview/about-marketplace-badges).

Are there other tools I can use to help me with this, or will I have to write my own makeshift TRX parser?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This action is open source and has a [License](https://github.com/EnricoMi/publish-unit-test-result-action/blob/master/LICENSE) allowing you to use it. Therefore, why not forking this action in your organization / workplace and use it from that fork? That way you'll be the action code owner and will be able to check / update whatever you want in the code according to the policies you need to follow.